# Isn't the depth of a convolutional layer, the number of colors (or colorspace size)?

Tags: cnn, convolution

I have been going through a CNN tutorial and noticed that depth of a convolutional layer is equal to the number of filters. But, shouldn't the depth be the number of colors in the image? I mean, if it's RGB then, depth is 3 right? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the depth of an image is equal to the color channels (1 for gray-scale images, 3 for RGB).

However, that is only the case for the **input layer** of the CNN. During the first convolution layer, the image can be passed through as many filters as we select. This number becomes the *depth* of the first layer. The subsequent layers can have **any depth we want**.

For example in the CNN depicted below:

[image]

The image input to the CNN initially has a depth of **1** (because it is gray-scale). The first convolutional layer passes it through 6 filters, so the depth of the first layer becomes **6**. The second layer passes the output of the first through 16 filters, meaning that the second layer has a depth of **16**, etc.

Comment: so, input depth is colorspace size, and further from there its always number of filters. Thank you very much